# How to change list of rules with the new list?

Tags: list-manipulation, rule

everyone!

I have the "big" list of rules

```
{{{Subscript[Abx, 1, 1] -> 182.745, Subscript[Aby, 1, 1] -> -248.194, 
   Subscript[Abz, 1, 1] -> -4.84702}, {Subscript[Abx, 1, 2] -> 
    150.256, Subscript[Aby, 1, 2] -> -247.769, 
   Subscript[Abz, 1, 2] -> -9.55877}, {Subscript[Abx, 1, 3] -> 
    130.968, Subscript[Aby, 1, 3] -> -248.306, 
   Subscript[Abz, 1, 3] -> -8.02836}, {Subscript[Abx, 1, 4] -> 
    115.461, Subscript[Aby, 1, 4] -> -247.891, 
   Subscript[Abz, 1, 4] -> -6.00448}, {Subscript[Abx, 1, 5] -> 
    94.3148, Subscript[Aby, 1, 5] -> -244.614, 
   Subscript[Abz, 1, 5] -> -9.23579}, {Subscript[Abx, 1, 6] -> 
    58.1106, Subscript[Aby, 1, 6] -> -236.562, 
   Subscript[Abz, 1, 6] -> -23.471}}, {{Subscript[Abx, 2, 1] -> 
    177.762, Subscript[Aby, 2, 1] -> -237.093, 
   Subscript[Abz, 2, 1] -> -1.47293}, {Subscript[Abx, 2, 2] -> 
    147.416, Subscript[Aby, 2, 2] -> -231.738, 
   Subscript[Abz, 2, 2] -> 4.79013}, {Subscript[Abx, 2, 3] -> 126.022,
    Subscript[Aby, 2, 3] -> -229.455, 
   Subscript[Abz, 2, 3] -> 4.0303}, {Subscript[Abx, 2, 4] -> 109.183, 
   Subscript[Aby, 2, 4] -> -229.908, 
   Subscript[Abz, 2, 4] -> -1.66963}, {Subscript[Abx, 2, 5] -> 92.502,
    Subscript[Aby, 2, 5] -> -232.762, 
   Subscript[Abz, 2, 5] -> -10.2268}, {Subscript[Abx, 2, 6] -> 
    71.5825, Subscript[Aby, 2, 6] -> -237.681, 
   Subscript[Abz, 2, 6] -> -19.5586}}, {{Subscript[Abx, 3, 1] -> 
    170.779, Subscript[Aby, 3, 1] -> -215.335, 
   Subscript[Abz, 3, 1] -> -4.99162}, {Subscript[Abx, 3, 2] -> 146.77,
    Subscript[Aby, 3, 2] -> -207.336, 
   Subscript[Abz, 3, 2] -> 8.01939}, {Subscript[Abx, 3, 3] -> 125.545,
    Subscript[Aby, 3, 3] -> -204.549, 
   Subscript[Abz, 3, 3] -> 6.21291}, {Subscript[Abx, 3, 4] -> 106.328,
    Subscript[Aby, 3, 4] -> -206.149, 
   Subscript[Abz, 3, 4] -> -3.10462}, {Subscript[Abx, 3, 5] -> 
    88.3402, Subscript[Aby, 3, 5] -> -211.312, 
   Subscript[Abz, 3, 5] -> -12.6268}, {Subscript[Abx, 3, 6] -> 
    70.8046, Subscript[Aby, 3, 6] -> -219.213, 
   Subscript[Abz, 3, 6] -> -15.0471}}, {{Subscript[Abx, 4, 1] -> 
    164.148, Subscript[Aby, 4, 1] -> -188.286, 
   Subscript[Abz, 4, 1] -> -7.95539}, {Subscript[Abx, 4, 2] -> 
    146.115, Subscript[Aby, 4, 2] -> -181.987, 
   Subscript[Abz, 4, 2] -> 7.21463}, {Subscript[Abx, 4, 3] -> 125.914,
    Subscript[Aby, 4, 3] -> -180.715, 
   Subscript[Abz, 4, 3] -> 4.65974}, {Subscript[Abx, 4, 4] -> 104.484,
    Subscript[Aby, 4, 4] -> -182.838, 
   Subscript[Abz, 4, 4] -> -5.5832}, {Subscript[Abx, 4, 5] -> 82.7611,
    Subscript[Aby, 4, 5] -> -186.726, 
   Subscript[Abz, 4, 5] -> -13.4774}, {Subscript[Abx, 4, 6] -> 
    61.6855, Subscript[Aby, 4, 6] -> -190.747, 
   Subscript[Abz, 4, 6] -> -8.9859}}, {{Subscript[Abx, 5, 1] -> 
    163.686, Subscript[Aby, 5, 1] -> -146.81, 
   Subscript[Abz, 5, 1] -> 18.7636}, {Subscript[Abx, 5, 2] -> 136.162,
    Subscript[Aby, 5, 2] -> -168.316, 
   Subscript[Abz, 5, 2] -> 25.2557}, {Subscript[Abx, 5, 3] -> 113.207,
    Subscript[Aby, 5, 3] -> -174.851, 
   Subscript[Abz, 5, 3] -> 16.284}, {Subscript[Abx, 5, 4] -> 91.4897, 
   Subscript[Aby, 5, 4] -> -171.11, 
   Subscript[Abz, 5, 4] -> 3.60073}, {Subscript[Abx, 5, 5] -> 67.6774,
    Subscript[Aby, 5, 5] -> -161.788, 
   Subscript[Abz, 5, 5] -> -1.04208}, {Subscript[Abx, 5, 6] -> 
    38.4379, Subscript[Aby, 5, 6] -> -151.578, 
   Subscript[Abz, 5, 6] -> 14.1077}}, {{Subscript[Abx, 6, 1] -> 
    161.356, Subscript[Aby, 6, 1] -> -139.776, 
   Subscript[Abz, 6, 1] -> 17.5727}, {Subscript[Abx, 6, 2] -> 135.981,
    Subscript[Aby, 6, 2] -> -158.154, 
   Subscript[Abz, 6, 2] -> 21.8456}, {Subscript[Abx, 6, 3] -> 114.701,
    Subscript[Aby, 6, 3] -> -164.777, 
   Subscript[Abz, 6, 3] -> 14.9072}, {Subscript[Abx, 6, 4] -> 94.1792,
    Subscript[Aby, 6, 4] -> -162.452, 
   Subscript[Abz, 6, 4] -> 5.23384}, {Subscript[Abx, 6, 5] -> 71.078, 
   Subscript[Aby, 6, 5] -> -153.983, 
   Subscript[Abz, 6, 5] -> 1.30202}, {Subscript[Abx, 6, 6] -> 42.0599,
    Subscript[Aby, 6, 6] -> -142.175, 
   Subscript[Abz, 6, 6] -> 11.5881}}}//MatrixForm
```

And the "small" one:

```
{Subscript[Abx, 5, 4] -> 1, Subscript[Abx, 5, 5] -> 2}
```

Can you please show me, how to update the "big" list with the "small" list? I really tried to manipulate such functions and conceptions like Associations or KeySelect, but it doesn't work... I understand, that it should be some not very complicated solution.

Thank you!

Comment: And a little addition. I understand, that in my example I can manually change the rule I need, but the size of the lists (“big” and “small” ones) can change and become huge, so I’d really want to know how to do it in rational way…

Comment: First, remove the `//MatrixForm` from the command as that gets in the way. Why not just Flatten the big list and then use Join? Like this `big=your big list here` and now do `big2 = Flatten[big]; combined = Join[big2, small];` where `small` is your small list. ? Why do you need the big list to have dimensions `{6,6,3}`?

Comment: “Big” is the matrix of control vertices of some Bezier surface, and it is very important not to lose its structure.

Comment: Then may be you can explain the logic of trying to add a list of only 2 elements in a list of dimensions {6,6,3}?  it is the wrong size in this case. Where will it go into the big list? I took you saying _how to update the "big" list with the "small" list?_ to mean you want to add the small list into the big one. If you mean something else, may be you could clarify.

Comment: A, OK! So, imagine that we have the "big" list as a storage for point coordinates. Then we preform some calculations and obtain that coordinates Abx5,4 and Abx5,5 should be recalculated with some values. In my example Abx5,4->1 and Abx5,5->2. So, after calculations and have to change the values of my storage (I mean my "big" list). So, before calculations Abx5,4-> 91.4897 and Abx5,5->67.6774 (it is all just for example), and after calculations 1 and 2 respectively. So, I need to "update" my "big" list with these new values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original matrix of rules

```
(rules = {{{Subscript[Abx, 1, 1] -> 182.745, Subscript[Aby, 1, 1] -> -248.194,
        Subscript[Abz, 1, 1] -> -4.84702}, {Subscript[Abx, 1, 2] -> 150.256, 
       Subscript[Aby, 1, 2] -> -247.769, 
       Subscript[Abz, 1, 2] -> -9.55877}, {Subscript[Abx, 1, 3] -> 130.968, 
       Subscript[Aby, 1, 3] -> -248.306, 
       Subscript[Abz, 1, 3] -> -8.02836}, {Subscript[Abx, 1, 4] -> 115.461, 
       Subscript[Aby, 1, 4] -> -247.891, 
       Subscript[Abz, 1, 4] -> -6.00448}, {Subscript[Abx, 1, 5] -> 94.3148, 
       Subscript[Aby, 1, 5] -> -244.614, 
       Subscript[Abz, 1, 5] -> -9.23579}, {Subscript[Abx, 1, 6] -> 58.1106, 
       Subscript[Aby, 1, 6] -> -236.562, 
       Subscript[Abz, 1, 6] -> -23.471}}, {{Subscript[Abx, 2, 1] -> 177.762, 
       Subscript[Aby, 2, 1] -> -237.093, 
       Subscript[Abz, 2, 1] -> -1.47293}, {Subscript[Abx, 2, 2] -> 147.416, 
       Subscript[Aby, 2, 2] -> -231.738, 
       Subscript[Abz, 2, 2] -> 4.79013}, {Subscript[Abx, 2, 3] -> 126.022, 
       Subscript[Aby, 2, 3] -> -229.455, 
       Subscript[Abz, 2, 3] -> 4.0303}, {Subscript[Abx, 2, 4] -> 109.183, 
       Subscript[Aby, 2, 4] -> -229.908, 
       Subscript[Abz, 2, 4] -> -1.66963}, {Subscript[Abx, 2, 5] -> 92.502, 
       Subscript[Aby, 2, 5] -> -232.762, 
       Subscript[Abz, 2, 5] -> -10.2268}, {Subscript[Abx, 2, 6] -> 71.5825, 
       Subscript[Aby, 2, 6] -> -237.681, 
       Subscript[Abz, 2, 6] -> -19.5586}}, {{Subscript[Abx, 3, 1] -> 170.779, 
       Subscript[Aby, 3, 1] -> -215.335, 
       Subscript[Abz, 3, 1] -> -4.99162}, {Subscript[Abx, 3, 2] -> 146.77, 
       Subscript[Aby, 3, 2] -> -207.336, 
       Subscript[Abz, 3, 2] -> 8.01939}, {Subscript[Abx, 3, 3] -> 125.545, 
       Subscript[Aby, 3, 3] -> -204.549, 
       Subscript[Abz, 3, 3] -> 6.21291}, {Subscript[Abx, 3, 4] -> 106.328, 
       Subscript[Aby, 3, 4] -> -206.149, 
       Subscript[Abz, 3, 4] -> -3.10462}, {Subscript[Abx, 3, 5] -> 88.3402, 
       Subscript[Aby, 3, 5] -> -211.312, 
       Subscript[Abz, 3, 5] -> -12.6268}, {Subscript[Abx, 3, 6] -> 70.8046, 
       Subscript[Aby, 3, 6] -> -219.213, 
       Subscript[Abz, 3, 6] -> -15.0471}}, {{Subscript[Abx, 4, 1] -> 164.148, 
       Subscript[Aby, 4, 1] -> -188.286, 
       Subscript[Abz, 4, 1] -> -7.95539}, {Subscript[Abx, 4, 2] -> 146.115, 
       Subscript[Aby, 4, 2] -> -181.987, 
       Subscript[Abz, 4, 2] -> 7.21463}, {Subscript[Abx, 4, 3] -> 125.914, 
       Subscript[Aby, 4, 3] -> -180.715, 
       Subscript[Abz, 4, 3] -> 4.65974}, {Subscript[Abx, 4, 4] -> 104.484, 
       Subscript[Aby, 4, 4] -> -182.838, 
       Subscript[Abz, 4, 4] -> -5.5832}, {Subscript[Abx, 4, 5] -> 82.7611, 
       Subscript[Aby, 4, 5] -> -186.726, 
       Subscript[Abz, 4, 5] -> -13.4774}, {Subscript[Abx, 4, 6] -> 61.6855, 
       Subscript[Aby, 4, 6] -> -190.747, 
       Subscript[Abz, 4, 6] -> -8.9859}}, {{Subscript[Abx, 5, 1] -> 163.686, 
       Subscript[Aby, 5, 1] -> -146.81, 
       Subscript[Abz, 5, 1] -> 18.7636}, {Subscript[Abx, 5, 2] -> 136.162, 
       Subscript[Aby, 5, 2] -> -168.316, 
       Subscript[Abz, 5, 2] -> 25.2557}, {Subscript[Abx, 5, 3] -> 113.207, 
       Subscript[Aby, 5, 3] -> -174.851, 
       Subscript[Abz, 5, 3] -> 16.284}, {Subscript[Abx, 5, 4] -> 91.4897, 
       Subscript[Aby, 5, 4] -> -171.11, 
       Subscript[Abz, 5, 4] -> 3.60073}, {Subscript[Abx, 5, 5] -> 67.6774, 
       Subscript[Aby, 5, 5] -> -161.788, 
       Subscript[Abz, 5, 5] -> -1.04208}, {Subscript[Abx, 5, 6] -> 38.4379, 
       Subscript[Aby, 5, 6] -> -151.578, 
       Subscript[Abz, 5, 6] -> 14.1077}}, {{Subscript[Abx, 6, 1] -> 161.356, 
       Subscript[Aby, 6, 1] -> -139.776, 
       Subscript[Abz, 6, 1] -> 17.5727}, {Subscript[Abx, 6, 2] -> 135.981, 
       Subscript[Aby, 6, 2] -> -158.154, 
       Subscript[Abz, 6, 2] -> 21.8456}, {Subscript[Abx, 6, 3] -> 114.701, 
       Subscript[Aby, 6, 3] -> -164.777, 
       Subscript[Abz, 6, 3] -> 14.9072}, {Subscript[Abx, 6, 4] -> 94.1792, 
       Subscript[Aby, 6, 4] -> -162.452, 
       Subscript[Abz, 6, 4] -> 5.23384}, {Subscript[Abx, 6, 5] -> 71.078, 
       Subscript[Aby, 6, 5] -> -153.983, 
       Subscript[Abz, 6, 5] -> 1.30202}, {Subscript[Abx, 6, 6] -> 42.0599, 
       Subscript[Aby, 6, 6] -> -142.175, Subscript[Abz, 6, 6] -> 11.5881}}}) //
   MatrixForm;
```

The list of updates

```
update = {Subscript[Abx, 5, 4] -> 1, Subscript[Abx, 5, 5] -> 2};
```

For comparison, the current values are

```
(First /@ update) /. Flatten[rules]

(* {91.4897, 67.6774} *)
```

The updated rules

```
updatedRules = rules /. ((#[[1]] -> val_) :> # & /@ update);
```

Verifying that the rules have been updated

```
(First /@ update) /. Flatten[updatedRules]

(* {1, 2} *)
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm trying to understand your syntax...) I'm very noobie in Wolfram Language yet.

Comment: For any unknown built-in symbols or operators, highlight them in Mathematica and press `F1` for help

Comment: I mean this manipulating with pure functions (I suppose all these "# and &" belong to that), it is something far for me yet...

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
bigList = {{Subscript[Abz, 5, 3] -> 16.284}, {Subscript[Abx, 5, 4] -> 
     91.4897, Subscript[Aby, 5, 4] -> -171.11, 
    Subscript[Abz, 5, 4] -> 3.60073}, {Subscript[Abx, 5, 5] -> 
     67.6774, Subscript[Aby, 5, 5] -> -161.788, 
    Subscript[Abz, 5, 5] -> -1.04208}};
smallList = {Subscript[Abx, 5, 4] -> 1, Subscript[Abx, 5, 5] -> 2};
newList = bigList /. {Rule[#[[1]], _] -> # & /@ smallList}
```

The syntax is that you are using the small list to create a substitution rule (`/.{target->replacement}`). You define a custom function (`function[#]&`) that takes the first element of each (`/@`) element (the elements are rules) in the short list and produces a match in the long list regardless of what the second element of the rule is there (the target is `Rule[#,_]`; it could also be written `#->_`) and substitutes that with the rule in the second list. This is performing the same function as Bob Hanlon's answer with trivial differences in the form of the expressions.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @АлександрМиллер You are welcome. It is good form to accept answers that you consider helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
rules = {{{Subscript[Abx, 1, 1] -> 182.745, 
    Subscript[Aby, 1, 1] -> -248.194, 
    Subscript[Abz, 1, 1] -> -4.84702}, {Subscript[Abx, 1, 2] -> 
     150.256, Subscript[Aby, 1, 2] -> -247.769, 
    Subscript[Abz, 1, 2] -> -9.55877}, {Subscript[Abx, 1, 3] -> 
     130.968, Subscript[Aby, 1, 3] -> -248.306, 
    Subscript[Abz, 1, 3] -> -8.02836}, {Subscript[Abx, 1, 4] -> 
     115.461, Subscript[Aby, 1, 4] -> -247.891, 
    Subscript[Abz, 1, 4] -> -6.00448}, {Subscript[Abx, 1, 5] -> 
     94.3148, Subscript[Aby, 1, 5] -> -244.614, 
    Subscript[Abz, 1, 5] -> -9.23579}, {Subscript[Abx, 1, 6] -> 
     58.1106, Subscript[Aby, 1, 6] -> -236.562, 
    Subscript[Abz, 1, 6] -> -23.471}}, {{Subscript[Abx, 2, 1] -> 
     177.762, Subscript[Aby, 2, 1] -> -237.093, 
    Subscript[Abz, 2, 1] -> -1.47293}, {Subscript[Abx, 2, 2] -> 
     147.416, Subscript[Aby, 2, 2] -> -231.738, 
    Subscript[Abz, 2, 2] -> 4.79013}, {Subscript[Abx, 2, 3] -> 
     126.022, Subscript[Aby, 2, 3] -> -229.455, 
    Subscript[Abz, 2, 3] -> 4.0303}, {Subscript[Abx, 2, 4] -> 109.183,
     Subscript[Aby, 2, 4] -> -229.908, 
    Subscript[Abz, 2, 4] -> -1.66963}, {Subscript[Abx, 2, 5] -> 
     92.502, Subscript[Aby, 2, 5] -> -232.762, 
    Subscript[Abz, 2, 5] -> -10.2268}, {Subscript[Abx, 2, 6] -> 
     71.5825, Subscript[Aby, 2, 6] -> -237.681, 
    Subscript[Abz, 2, 6] -> -19.5586}}, {{Subscript[Abx, 3, 1] -> 
     170.779, Subscript[Aby, 3, 1] -> -215.335, 
    Subscript[Abz, 3, 1] -> -4.99162}, {Subscript[Abx, 3, 2] -> 
     146.77, Subscript[Aby, 3, 2] -> -207.336, 
    Subscript[Abz, 3, 2] -> 8.01939}, {Subscript[Abx, 3, 3] -> 
     125.545, Subscript[Aby, 3, 3] -> -204.549, 
    Subscript[Abz, 3, 3] -> 6.21291}, {Subscript[Abx, 3, 4] -> 
     106.328, Subscript[Aby, 3, 4] -> -206.149, 
    Subscript[Abz, 3, 4] -> -3.10462}, {Subscript[Abx, 3, 5] -> 
     88.3402, Subscript[Aby, 3, 5] -> -211.312, 
    Subscript[Abz, 3, 5] -> -12.6268}, {Subscript[Abx, 3, 6] -> 
     70.8046, Subscript[Aby, 3, 6] -> -219.213, 
    Subscript[Abz, 3, 6] -> -15.0471}}, {{Subscript[Abx, 4, 1] -> 
     164.148, Subscript[Aby, 4, 1] -> -188.286, 
    Subscript[Abz, 4, 1] -> -7.95539}, {Subscript[Abx, 4, 2] -> 
     146.115, Subscript[Aby, 4, 2] -> -181.987, 
    Subscript[Abz, 4, 2] -> 7.21463}, {Subscript[Abx, 4, 3] -> 
     125.914, Subscript[Aby, 4, 3] -> -180.715, 
    Subscript[Abz, 4, 3] -> 4.65974}, {Subscript[Abx, 4, 4] -> 
     104.484, Subscript[Aby, 4, 4] -> -182.838, 
    Subscript[Abz, 4, 4] -> -5.5832}, {Subscript[Abx, 4, 5] -> 
     82.7611, Subscript[Aby, 4, 5] -> -186.726, 
    Subscript[Abz, 4, 5] -> -13.4774}, {Subscript[Abx, 4, 6] -> 
     61.6855, Subscript[Aby, 4, 6] -> -190.747, 
    Subscript[Abz, 4, 6] -> -8.9859}}, {{Subscript[Abx, 5, 1] -> 
     163.686, Subscript[Aby, 5, 1] -> -146.81, 
    Subscript[Abz, 5, 1] -> 18.7636}, {Subscript[Abx, 5, 2] -> 
     136.162, Subscript[Aby, 5, 2] -> -168.316, 
    Subscript[Abz, 5, 2] -> 25.2557}, {Subscript[Abx, 5, 3] -> 
     113.207, Subscript[Aby, 5, 3] -> -174.851, 
    Subscript[Abz, 5, 3] -> 16.284}, {Subscript[Abx, 5, 4] -> 91.4897,
     Subscript[Aby, 5, 4] -> -171.11, 
    Subscript[Abz, 5, 4] -> 3.60073}, {Subscript[Abx, 5, 5] -> 
     67.6774, Subscript[Aby, 5, 5] -> -161.788, 
    Subscript[Abz, 5, 5] -> -1.04208}, {Subscript[Abx, 5, 6] -> 
     38.4379, Subscript[Aby, 5, 6] -> -151.578, 
    Subscript[Abz, 5, 6] -> 14.1077}}, {{Subscript[Abx, 6, 1] -> 
     161.356, Subscript[Aby, 6, 1] -> -139.776, 
    Subscript[Abz, 6, 1] -> 17.5727}, {Subscript[Abx, 6, 2] -> 
     135.981, Subscript[Aby, 6, 2] -> -158.154, 
    Subscript[Abz, 6, 2] -> 21.8456}, {Subscript[Abx, 6, 3] -> 
     114.701, Subscript[Aby, 6, 3] -> -164.777, 
    Subscript[Abz, 6, 3] -> 14.9072}, {Subscript[Abx, 6, 4] -> 
     94.1792, Subscript[Aby, 6, 4] -> -162.452, 
    Subscript[Abz, 6, 4] -> 5.23384}, {Subscript[Abx, 6, 5] -> 71.078,
     Subscript[Aby, 6, 5] -> -153.983, 
    Subscript[Abz, 6, 5] -> 1.30202}, {Subscript[Abx, 6, 6] -> 
     42.0599, Subscript[Aby, 6, 6] -> -142.175, 
    Subscript[Abz, 6, 6] -> 11.5881}}}
```

---

```
update = {Subscript[Abx, 5, 4] -> 1, Subscript[Abx, 5, 5] -> 2}

pos = Level[(Most /@ Position[rules, First@#] & /@ update), {-2}]
```

These are the positions where replacements happen:

> {{5, 4, 1}, {5, 5, 1}}

```
ReplacePart[rules, Thread[pos -> update]]
```

[image]